# how to provide space between span and div

Tags: css

I want to give space between span and div which is as follow

```
<span class="headingUserName">JAVA MAN</span>
<div class="home-middle">
 Content
</div>
```

in My external css file

```
.headingUserName{
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
```

this is not providing space between div and span.How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
.home-middle
{
   margin-top:10px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QcADb/)

or as Vector's Solution

```
.headingUserName {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: can we not provide margin with span

Comment: if you want use *margin-bottom* with span then see @vector solution.

Comment: @Sachine ok for that we should make div css display:block;

Comment: *display:block;* with span's css class

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<style>
.headingUserName{
    font-size: 24px;


}

.home-middle
{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block` to the span styling

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/Ep8G8/

```
.headingUserName {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the display to `block` will surely do what you are looking for. But it also will make your `span` element to cover all the width, because block elements has by default a 100% width.

If you don't want this, you can use `inline-block` instead. Your element stays with an automatic width but you can set it to have margins as in block elements.

```
.headingUserName{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted the Span to provide the spacing, for some reason, you would have to set its display property to block, like this:

```
.headingUserName{
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
```